# jquery .load() Ajax does not load script tag

Tags: jquery, ajax, scripting

i tried many topics but i didn't get any result.

by this code:

```
<script>
function url(){
  $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $("#loading").show();
  }).ajaxStop(function(){
    $("#loading").hide();
  }).ajaxError(function(){
  alert("error on load page!");
  });
  $("#div1").load("ajax_load.asp #page");
  };
</script>
```

when the page load, the scripts didn't load.
how can i fix this code?
i try many codes and tips but all of them didn't work.

any idea's?
sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 1):

Remove space between `ajax_load.asp #page` like this `ajax_load.asp#page` and you also need to call the `url()` `function`

Try below code:

```
<script>
function url(){
  $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $("#loading").show();
  }).ajaxStop(function(){
    $("#loading").hide();
  }).ajaxError(function(){
  alert("error on load page!");
  });
  $("#div1").load("ajax_load.asp#page");
  };

  url();
</script>
```